# comparing two csv files and getting the row that is not present in third file

Tags: python, pandas

I've seen many questions like this one here, but none of the solutions helped me. So lets say we have two csv files like this:

**File1 (original)**

```
3L261   6/27/2022 1:15  AUH SLL ACT 320
3L122   4/6/2022 23:35  CCJ AUH ACT 320
3L133   4/5/2022 8:45   AUH TRV ACT 320
```

**File2 (system generated)**

```
3L122   4/6/2022 23:35  CCJ AUH ACT 320
```

What i am trying to achive is to compare row 1 of file1 with the entire rows of file2, if the row exist then move to the next row of file1 and do the exact comparison again. if the row does not exist then output the row to another file comparion.csv

I tried the following code but it compares row1 of file1 with row1 of file2 , row2 of file1 with row 2 of file 2. Need to know how i can achieve my use case.

**expected output**

```
3L261   6/27/2022 1:15  AUH SLL ACT 320
3L133   4/5/2022 8:45   AUH TRV ACT 320

import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

with open('file1.csv', 'r') as f, open('file.csv', 'r') as s, open('Comparison.csv', 'w') as o:
    diffs = 0
    for i, (first, second) in enumerate(zip(f, s), start=1):
        if first != second:
            print((f'row #{i}\n'
                   f'in first file: {first.strip()}\n'
                   f'in second file: {second.strip()}'), file=o)
            diffs += 1
    print(f'Different values on {diffs} row(s), same values on {i-diffs} row(s)')
```

Comment: please provide a minimal input as **text**, and the matching expected output

Comment: file 1  

3L261 6/27/2022 1:15 AUH SLL ACT 320
3L122 4/6/2022 23:35 CCJ AUH ACT 320
3L133 4/5/2022 8:45 AUH TRV ACT 320           

file 2
3L122 4/6/2022 23:35 CCJ AUH ACT 320

expected output 
3L261 6/27/2022 1:15 AUH SLL ACT 320
3L133 4/5/2022 8:45 AUH TRV ACT 320

Comment: please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71925814/edit) the question

Comment: Read all of the lines in file.csv into memory. Read file1.csv line by line. Check if a line from file1.csv exists in the in-memory list. If it doesn't exist, write it to Comparison.csv. A naive approach to this could be **very** inefficient. You should consider sorting the lines from file.csv and implementing a binary search for greater efficiency

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your problem is about how to relate the lines of a dataFrame, right?

Before that, excuse me for my English.

In my opinion the simplest way to do this is using the `==` operator.
I will demonstrate with a simple example how this can be done.

```
import pandas as pd

data_season1 = {"Player": ["Lewandowski", "Haland", "Ronaldo", "Messi", "Mbappe"],
                "Goals": [10, 8, 6, 5, 4]}

data_season2 = {"Player": ["Lewandowski", "Haland", "Ronaldo", "Messi", "Mbappe"],
                "Goals": [7, 8, 6, 7, 4]}

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_season1)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_season2)

print(df_1 == df_2)
```

Result:

```
   Player  Goals
0    True  False
1    True   True
2    True   True
3    True  False
4    True   True
```

Compares the corresponding elements of `df_1` to ad `df_2` and returns True if the corresponding elements of that position are the same, otherwise returns False.

We can use `pandas.DataFrame.all()` method to know which rows are the same in both `df_1` and `df_2`.

```
import pandas as pd

data_season1 = {"Player": ["Lewandowski", "Haland", "Ronaldo", "Messi", "Mbappe"],
                "Goals": [10, 8, 6, 5, 4]}

data_season2 = {"Player": ["Lewandowski", "Haland", "Ronaldo", "Messi", "Mbappe"],
                "Goals": [7, 8, 6, 7, 4]}

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_season1)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_season2)

print((df_1 == df_2).all(axis=1))
```

Result:

```
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
```

Lines with a value of `True` in the output have the same value as the corresponding elements. Thus, lines with a value of `False` in the output have different values ​​than the corresponding elements.

We can use indexing to list all rows whose values ​​differ in `df_1` and `df_2`.

```
import pandas as pd

data_season1 = {"Player": ["Lewandowski", "Haland", "Ronaldo", "Messi", "Mbappe"],
                "Goals": [10, 8, 6, 5, 4]}

data_season2 = {"Player": ["Lewandowski", "Haland", "Ronaldo", "Messi", "Mbappe"],
                "Goals": [7, 8, 6, 7, 4]}

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_season1)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_season2)

print(df_1[(df_1 == df_2).all(axis=1) == False])
```

Result:

```
        Player  Goals
0  Lewandowski     10
3        Messi      5
```

Lists all rows in `df_1` that have different values ​​than the corresponding rows in `df_2`.

If we have different indices for `df_1` and `df_2`, we get an error saying ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects.

```
import pandas as pd

data_season1 = {"Player": ["Lewandowski", "Haland", "Ronaldo", "Messi", "Mbappe"],
                "Goals": [10, 8, 6, 5, 4]}

data_season2 = {"Player": ["Lewandowski", "Haland", "Ronaldo", "Messi", "Mbappe"],
                "Goals": [7, 8, 6, 7, 4]}

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_season1)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_season2, index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

print(df_1 == df_2)
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects
```

We can use the `pandas.DataFrame.reset_index()`  method to reset the indexes in order to overcome the above mentioned problem.

```
import pandas as pd

data_season1 = {"Player": ["Lewandowski", "Haland", "Ronaldo", "Messi", "Mbappe"],
                "Goals": [10, 8, 6, 5, 4]}

data_season2 = {"Player": ["Lewandowski", "Haland", "Ronaldo", "Messi", "Mbappe"],
                "Goals": [7, 8, 6, 7, 4]}

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_season1)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_season2, index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
df_2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

print(df_1 == df_2)
```

Result:

```
   Player  Goals
0    True  False
1    True   True
2    True   True
3    True  False
4    True   True
```

Resets the index of `df_2` before comparing `df_1` and `df_2`, so that two dataframes have the same indices to make the comparison possible.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform an outer `merge` with `indicator=True` and use it to export new files:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('filename1'.csv, header=None) # or set headers accordingly
df1 = pd.read_csv('filename2.csv', header=None)

for name, g in df1.merge(df2, how='outer', indicator=True).groupby('_merge'):
    g.drop(columns='_merge').to_csv(f'{name}.csv', header=None, index=False)
```

output:

```
# left_only.csv
3L261,6/27/2022 1:15,AUH,SLL,ACT,320
3L133,4/5/2022 8:45,AUH,TRV,ACT,320

# right_only.csv
3L122,4/6/2022 23:35,CCJ,AUH,ACT,320

# both.csv
[empty file]
```

Comment: this does not seem to work for me . I get the below error    ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

Comment: @francis this means you have different types, can you provide the output of `df1.dtypes` and `df2.dtypes`?

Comment: df1 FLIGHT_NUMBER     object
DEPARTURE_DATE    object
ORIGIN            object
DESTINATION       object
STATUS            object
MODEL_NUMBER      object   df2 FLIGHT_NUMBER     object
DEPARTURE_DATE    object
ORIGIN            object
DESTINATION       object
STATUS            object
MODEL_NUMBER       int64
dtype: object

Comment: @francis here is the issue, you have strings for MODEL_NUMBER in one dataframe and int64 in the other one. Ensure to have the same type in both

Comment: thanks fixed the issue but the output generated is a blank file. should not be the case